# Why does "as adj. as do something" works?

Tags: grammar

I saw such a sentence:

> They became convinced that the details of these patterns were as distinctive of a particular group of animals as were anatomical characteristics.

Normally we use "A(a noun) is as distinctive as B(a noun)". Why does it use "A is as distinctive as is something(a noun)"?

What is this kind of grammar called?

Besides, why is it "as distinctive of a particular group as"? I believe distinctive is an adjective...

Comment: Yes, it's an adjective. This rice is *as good as* cooked. But the sample could place *to be* later or not at all:  as [were] anatomical characteristics **were**. "The group details were as distinctive as the physical difference."

Comment: I'm confused why can we say "distinctive of a particular group". I think we should use "something of a particular group” rather than "adjective of a particular group"...

Comment: Some adjectives can be used with _of_ - 'typical of', 'characteristic of' - also 'it was kind of you to do that', meaning 'you showed kindness by doing it'.

Comment: [word to the wise: *I saw a sentence like this*. "such as this" does not work here. It would work here: A sentence such as this can be hard/easy to understand.]

Comment: as...as is a comparative usage. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/as-as You have two questions. I am only giving a hint for the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction is

- ... *the details of these patterns were as distinctive of a particular group of animals as anatomical characteristics were distinctive of a particular group of animals.*

This would inevitably be shortened to

- ... *the details of these patterns were as distinctive of a particular group of animals as anatomical characteristics were*.

The subject-auxiliary inversion in your example is fine, though a formal device.

'Be distinctive of' is a less common way of saying 'be a distinguishing feature of'; 'serve to identify' is a formal synonym.

A paraphrase of the original is

- *They became convinced that these unique individual patterns provided as foolproof a way of identifying a particular group of animals as anatomical characteristics did.*